# Inverse Function Derivative

Tags: calculus

I have been given the function: $f(x)=x^5+3x-2$. How do I find the inverse of this. When I switch x and y, it just goes downhill from there and I'm not even sure what I'm supposed to do after I figure out the inverse. Is there any tricks to find the inverse with the powers??

Comment: I don't think that there is a closed form for the inverse, if that's what you're after.

Comment: Well I'm not even sure how to find it in the first place

Comment: If you can find one, the approach you mentioned is usually the way to go. But you still might find the derivative by deriving $x = f(f^{-1}(x))$

Comment: finding the derivative of the inverse function is not as hard as finding the inverse itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the title it looks more as if you need the formula for the derivative of the inverse (without knowing the inverse)?

When $y_0=f(x_0)$ and $f'(x_0)\neq 0$ then the $C^1$ function $f$ has a local $C^1$ inverse $g$ defined in a neighborhood $N_y$ of $y_0$ with values in a neighborhood $N_x$ of $x_0$. One has $f(g(y))=y$ for $y\in N_y$ and $g(f(x))=x$ for $x\in N_x$ which by taking derivatives leads to:
$$ g'(y_0)=\frac{1}{f'(x_0)} = \frac{1}{f'(g(y_0))} $$
So for example $f(1)=2$, $f'(1)=8$ so the local inverse at $2$ verifies $g'(2)=1/8$. In the present case $f$ is strictly increasing and is bijection onto ${\Bbb R}$ so $g$ is defined on all of ${\Bbb R}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify that $f$ is strictly monotonous, so an inverse $g=f^{-1}$ exists. Then we know that $y = f(g(y))$. We can derive this equation and get $$ 1 = f'(g(y)) g'(y)$$

This implies for the point $x=f(x)$ that

$$ g'(y) = g'(f(x)) = \frac{1}{f'(g(y))} = \frac{1}{f'(x)}$$